# Change detection with observable in Angular 7

Tags: angular, observable, ionic4, angular-changedetection

I have a avatar component that gets the user ID and searches for the user Avatar in a link, and show it inside an IMG tag

```html
<ion-avatar [ngClass]="cssClass">
  <img
  [src]="avatar"
  onError="this.src='assets/images/profile1.jpg'" />
</ion-avatar>
```

```
 getAvatar() {
    this.userService.getAvatar(this.channelId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.avatar = res;
      });
  }
```

but when I call a function to change the user profile picture

`this.userService.changeProfilePicture(picture, this.myChannelId).subscribe(...);`

the profile picture is updated inside this link and the url stay the same, but in the it doesn't update in view even when I destroy the component and reload it. I tried to create a random timestamp and append it to the link every time I reload the page. This works well, but load the same image several times inside the memory.

Is there anyway to use the ChangeDetection to tell the view to update when I change my profile picture ?

The `getAvatar()` function is a observable that emits a link, I don't know if this works

```
  getAvatar(channelId): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable(o => {
      o.next(`link to the avatar with the specific channel id`);
      o.complete();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing change detector in your component and detecting the changes manually?

```
constructor(public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

 getAvatar() {
    this.userService.getAvatar(this.channelId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.avatar = res;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      });
  }
```

Comment: I tried but nothing happens, this function detect changes when an observable emits a change ?

Comment: Im using this property in ``@Component`` decorator ``changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush``

Comment: `OnPush` tells the parent component to only update the `@Input()`s of the component to increase speed and try to help encourage immutability. So in your case, running detectChanges should force the component to check that value for changes.

And yes, in your subscription as well. As long as the value that you're returning is a string and that string is different than what was originally there.

Comment: The link string stays the same but the image inside that changes

Comment: Ahhh.... That's why. The value actually needs to change for the value to be updated. You would need to trigger a refresh or something most likely since the value is never changing.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all You can try to change

```
 getAvatar(channelId): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable(o => {
      o.next(`link to the avatar with the specific channel id`);
      o.complete();
    });
  }
```

to

```
 getAvatar(channelId): Observable<string> {
    return of('some test result')
    });
  }
```

in order to ensure Your data pipe is OK (only to test).
I afraid by returning `new Observable` every request and also using `o.complete();`
you're actually make it "promise like".

Technically Angular should take care of all Your change detection, but check if Your component has  `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on signature, this means **no automatic change detection**. in this case You have to trigger detection manually by using `ChangeDetectorRef`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-name',
  template: `{{count}}`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class SomeComponent { 
  count = 0;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.count = 5;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }, 1000);

  }

}
```

for more info pls see [this awesome post](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4) by Netanel Basal

Comment: try this: `onError="this.avatar='assets/images/profile1.jpg'"`